# Configuring Selenium in Intellij offline

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, testng

I have an issue with configuring Selenium in Intellij offline. The thing is, when I configure maven project and add dependency to pom.xml then Intellij is trying to download all the updates but it has no access, firewall is blocking it. Can i download Selenium and TestNg repo and implement it in the project by myslef? If yes then how Can I configure it? Thank you very much for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the Selenium and TestNG related jar files manually and save them into project folder, then add them into dependency as system scope and refer to it by its full path. Consider that the JAR is located in /lib. Then add the dependency in your pom.xml file as following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.roufid.tutorials</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>

// ${basedir} represents the directory containing pom.xml.
```

Comment: Ok so it returns that cannot resole file 'path/selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar' well do  i need to update maven?

Comment: Ok maven successfully found selenium but i have now problem with testng, it cant see this jar...